# Can't get WINS name broadcasting to work on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, networking

A client of mine has a new MacBook. I'm trying to setup [Synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/). I've got it working where I can run the server on the Mac, and connect to it from the PC, using the Mac's ip address.

I do not want to put in static ip addresses. I want to get some sort of name resolution working. A DNS server is not available, so I want to use WINS.

I entered a wins name and workgroup under System Preferences -> Network -> Eternet -> Advanced -> WINS, but it does not work. (Tested using nmblookup on the Mac, and ping on the pc)

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but I found it before finding an actual answer elsewhere, so I'm putting it here in hopes it helps someone else.

To make the Mac respond to smb name requests, turn on File sharing. I don't think you actually have to share anything, but sharing needs to be turned on in System Preferences / Sharing / File Sharing.

Comment: Fixed it for me on macOS 13.